# Microsoft Graph API get user presence for an API tool

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following problem.

For an internal tool I am developing for my company i need the teams status of every employee.

I registered the application in azure and tried the secret credential auth flow.
But then i discovered that i for application auth flow getting the presence is not supported. (Also added the permission to get presence as an application and delegation)

Than i tried delegation auth flow and I just can't get it work.
It need to be able to get the presence without any user interaction since this tool is an CLI/API tool for other tools to use.
And it needs to be in C#.

Is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Get user presence is supported only with delegated permission for now.

According this [thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-presence-should-support-application-permissions/idc-p/3840933/highlight/true#M1803), support for application permission should be ready for [beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) in Q4/2023.

Comment: OK but i also have problems using the auth flows for delegated permission. 
Do I understand correctly that i can't have delegated authentication without any user interaction? 
Because i need this to be deployed on a server which doesn't have desktop environment.